# Function that returns minimal cover of a list S by given list of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list `S` and a list of sublists `L = { SL[1], SL[2], ... , SL[n] }` of which I know that they cover `S`, i.e. for each element in `S` there is at least one sublist that contains that element.
I'm looking for a way to efficiently create a minimal cover for `S` by elements of `L`. The way this cover is represented doesn't really matter.
The problem sizes I have in mind are have `Length[L]` about 100000, `Length[SL[i]]` about 10 `Length[S]` about 5000.

**Background**

I'm  interested in applying such functionality to situations where

- E is a list of equations
- S a list of variables

and I'm searching for a smallest set of equations for which each variable in S is present. The list of equations is often very long, but this way, I could have a small subset that contains all the variables in S. (of course, I would have to map each equation to its list of variables first to link this problem to the above).

Comment: Have you seen this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224697/72682 ? The cost could be the LeafCount of your equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2:** Adding an optional third argument specifying target variables and embellishing the output with additional properties (code below):

```
varCover[equations]["Properties"]
```

> ```
> {"Solution", "CoverIndices", "Cover", "VariablesInCover",  
>  "Cost", "HighlightedExpressions", "Input", "Expressions", "Weights",
>  "TargetVariables", "Variables", "CoverageMatrix",  
>  "HighlightedCoverageMatrix", "RelationGraph", 
>  "HighlightedGraph", "Properties"}
> ```

```
varCover[equations]["Cover"]
```

> ```
> {y + z == 6, Sqrt[b - c^3] x == 3, 3 a - w == 4}
> ```

```
varCover[equations]["HighlightedExpressions"]
```

[image]

```
varCover[equations]["HighlightedCoverageMatrix"]
```

[image]

```
varCover[equations]["HighlightedGraph"]
```

[image]

If any of the target variables (specified in the third argument) does not appear in expressions (specified in the first argument) it is highlighted in associated results:

```
varCover[equations, 
  Automatic, {x, w, c, blah1, blah2}]["HighlightedExpressions"]
```

[image]

```
varCover[equations, 
  Automatic, {x, w, c, blah1, blah2}]["HighlightedCoverageMatrix"]
```

[image]

```
varCover[equations, 
  Automatic, {x, w, c, blah1, blah2}]["HighlightedGraph"]
```

[image]

---

#### Code

```
ClearAll[varCover]

varCover[expressions_, weights_ : Automatic, targetvariables_ : Automatic] := 
 Module[{$vars = Level[#, {-1}, DeleteCases[_?NumericQ]@*Union@*List] &, 
   properties = {"Solution", "CoverIndices", "Cover", 
     "VariablesInCover", "Cost", "HighlightedExpressions", "Input", 
     "Expressions", "Weights", "TargetVariables", "Variables", 
     "CoverageMatrix", "HighlightedCoverageMatrix", "RelationGraph", 
     "HighlightedGraph", "Properties"}, 
   highlighting = {v : Alternatives @@ # :>
       Placed[ Highlighted[v, Frame -> True], Before],
      v : (Alternatives @@ #2) :>
       Placed[v /. tv : Alternatives @@ #3 :>
          Highlighted[tv, Background -> LightRed, Frame -> True], 
        After]} &}, 
  Module[{bpg, hbpg, m, cm, sol, d, ivl, uvl, notcovered, pos, sel, 
    w = weights /. Automatic -> ConstantArray[1, Length@expressions],
    vl = Apply[Union]@Map[$vars]@expressions},
    ivl = Intersection[vl, targetvariables /. Automatic -> vl];
    uvl = DeleteDuplicates@Join[vl, targetvariables /. Automatic -> {}];
    notcovered = Complement[uvl, vl];
    m = Boole@Outer[MemberQ[$vars@#2, #] &, ivl, expressions];
    sol = First @ LinearOptimization[w . d, 
      {m . d \[VectorGreaterEqual] 1., 
       0. \[VectorLessEqual] d \[VectorLessEqual] 1.}, 
      d ∈ Vectors[Length@expressions, Integers]];
    pos = PositionIndex[d /. sol][1];
    sel = expressions[[pos]];
    cm = Transpose @
     Boole @ Outer[MemberQ[$vars @ #2, #] &, uvl, expressions];
   bpg = RelationGraph[MemberQ[$vars@#, #2] &, expressions, uvl, 
     VertexCoordinates -> 
      GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[Length /@ {expressions, uvl}]], 
     VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v , Before], 
       v : (Alternatives @@ uvl) :> Placed[v, After]}];
   hbpg = HighlightGraph[bpg,
      Subgraph[bpg, DirectedEdge[Alternatives @@ sel, _]], 
      GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
      VertexLabels -> highlighting[sel, uvl, notcovered]];
   AssociationThread[properties, 
     {d, pos, sel, $vars /@ sel, w . d, 
      Column[Join[expressions, notcovered] /. 
          highlighting[sel, uvl, notcovered] /. Placed -> (# &)], 
      AssociationThread[{"Expressions", "Weights", 
         "TargetVariables"}, {expressions, w, targetvariables}], 
      expressions, w, targetvariables, vl,
      Panel @ TableForm[cm, TableHeadings -> {expressions, uvl}], 
      Panel @ TableForm[cm, TableHeadings -> ({expressions, uvl} /. 
             highlighting[sel, uvl, notcovered] /. Placed -> (# &))], 
      Panel @ bpg, Panel @ hbpg, properties} /. sol]]]
```

---

**Update:** A function that takes a list of expressions and, optionally, a cost vector; sets up and solves the associated `LinearOptimization` problem; and returns an `Association` with keys `"Inputs"`, `"Decisions"`, `"Indices"`, `"Selection"`, `"Variables"` and `"Cost"`:

```
ClearAll[varCover]

varCover[eq_, costs_ : Automatic][q_ : Automatic] :=
 Module[{$vars = Level[#, {-1}, DeleteCases[_?NumericQ]@* Union@*List] &},
  Module[{assoc, sol, d, pos,
    c = costs /. Automatic -> ConstantArray[1, Length@eq],
    m = Boole@Outer[MemberQ[$vars@#2, #] &, Apply[Union]@Map[$vars]@eq, eq]},
   sol = First @
     LinearOptimization[c . d,
      {m . d \[VectorGreaterEqual] 1., 
       0. \[VectorLessEqual] d \[VectorLessEqual] 1.},
      Element[d, Vectors[Length@eq, Integers]]];
   pos = PositionIndex[d /. sol][1];
   assoc = AssociationThread[
      {"Inputs", "Decision", "Indices", "Selection", "Variables", "Cost"},
     {AssociationThread[{"Equations", "Costs"}, {eq, c}], d,  pos, 
       eq[[pos]], $vars /@ eq[[pos]], c . d} /. sol];
   q /. {Automatic -> assoc, _ -> Lookup[q] @ assoc}]]
```

***Examples***

```
varCover[equations][]
```

[image]

```
varCover[equations][{"Indices", "Selection", "Variables"}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 5}, 
>  {y + z == 6, Sqrt[b - c^3] x == 3, 3 a - w == 4}, 
>  {{y, z}, {b, c, x}, {a, w}}}
> ```

---

**Original answer:**

### [Linear Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearOptimization.html)

This is a simple adaptation of the example in [Linear Optimization >> Applications >> Set Covering Problems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearOptimization.html).

Using @flinty's input example:

```
equations = {x^2 + 2 a - 3 w^(z + 1) == x,
   y + z == 6, 
   x Sqrt[b - c^3] == 3, 
   b + 1 == 0, 
   3 a - w == 4,
   Cos[x]/4 + z == -5,
   Log[a] + Log[b] == Sqrt[x + 1],   
   Sqrt[x + Sqrt[Cos[y]] - Sqrt[Sin[z] + 1]/a*b]};


varList = Level[#, {-1}, DeleteCases[_?NumericQ] @* Union @* List] &;


allvars = Apply[Union] @ Map[varList] @ equations
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, w, x, y, z}
> ```

```
memberships = Boole @ Outer[MemberQ[varList @ #2, #] &, allvars, equations];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ memberships
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
solution = First @ LinearOptimization[
   ConstantArray[1, Length @ equations] . decisions,
   {memberships . decisions \[VectorGreaterEqual] 1.,
    0. \[VectorLessEqual] decisions \[VectorLessEqual] 1.},
   Element[decisions, Vectors[Length @ equations, Integers]]]
```

> ```
>  decisions -> {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

```
selectedequations = Pick[equations, Values @ solution, 1];
selectedindices = Flatten @ PositionIndex[Values @ solution][1]

TeXForm @ Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & @
 Prepend[{{Column @ selectedindices, 
      Column @ selectedequations, 
      Column[varList /@ selectedequations], 
      Union @@ (varList /@ selectedequations)}}, 
    {"indices", 
     "selectedequations", 
     "selectedvariables", 
     "Union @ selectedvariables"}]
```

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{indices} & \text{selectedequations} & \text{selectedvariables} & \text{Union @ selectedvariables} \\
\hline
\begin{array}{l}
 2 \\
 3 \\
 5 \\
\end{array}
 & 
\begin{array}{l}
 y+z=6 \\
 x \sqrt{b-c^3}=3 \\
 3 a-w=4 \\
\end{array}
 & 
\begin{array}{l}
 \{y,z\} \\
 \{b,c,x\} \\
 \{a,w\} \\
\end{array}
 & \{a,b,c,w,x,y,z\} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Note:** Minimizing an alternative objective function that weights each equation with the number of variables in it, that is, using

```
 (Length /@ varList /@ equations) . decisions
```

instead of `ConstantArray[1, Length @ equations] . decisions` as the objective gives the same solution for this example.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my greedy solution from the answer mentioned in the comments, adapted for equations / variables. Note that greedy is not optimal, but generally performs well as the problem size grows. For very large problems it becomes intractable to solve using ILP and other methods, and the greedy algorithm is usually good enough ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm))

```
greedyfactor[curunion_, set_] := 
 If[ContainsAll[curunion, set[[1]]], Infinity, 
  set[[2]]/(Length[Union[curunion, set[[1]]]] - Length[curunion])]

greedy[sets_] := 
 Module[{target = Union @@ sets[[All, 1]], remaining = sets, 
   curunion = {}, sel}, 
  Reap[While[! ContainsAll[curunion, target], 
     sel = First[MinimalBy[remaining, greedyfactor[curunion, #] &]];
     Sow[sel];
     remaining = DeleteCases[remaining, sel];
     curunion = Union[curunion, sel[[1]]]]][[-1, 1]]]

equations = {
   x^2 + 2 a - 3 w^(z + 1) == x,
   y + z == 6,
   x Sqrt[b - c^3] == 3,
   b + 1 == 0,
   3 a - w == 4,
   Cos[x]/4 + z == -5,
   Log[a] + Log[b] == Sqrt[x + 1],
   Sqrt[x + Sqrt[Cos[y]] - Sqrt[Sin[z] + 1]/a*b]
};

getSymbols[expr_] := 
  Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, Except[_?NumericQ, _Symbol], Infinity];

allvariables = getSymbols[equations];
sets = {getSymbols[#], LeafCount[#]} & /@ equations;

(*confirm we cover all elements*)
chosenSets = greedy[sets];
indices = First[FirstPosition[sets, #]] & /@ chosenSets;
equations[[indices]]

(** {y + z == 6, Log[a] + Log[b] == Sqrt[1 + x], 3 a - w == 4, 
 Sqrt[b - c^3] x == 3} **)
```

Comment: I think you need a pattern like `Except[_?NumericQ, _Symbol]` in `Cases[...]` to leave numeric symbols like `E` and `Pi`.

Comment: @kglr thanks. OP may want to also have equations like `x+1 == f[g[y]]` and have all of x, f, g, y as variables, but not sure how to do that. Adding `Heads->True` doesn't work.

Comment: @flinty In my special case I know that all variables are labeled by ```s[i]``` with s a chosen symbol and ```i``` an integer so just ```Cases[ expr, s[_], Infinity ]``` does the job. Thanks for the Wikipedia link btw :)